# MWAA CLI - Stop Dags Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I'm using AWS MWAA 2.6.3 and I'm trying to mark an execution of dag as Failed using run_id, is there anyway to do that using boto3 MWAA, since we can't use the backend APIs;

thanks!